# Is 0 divided by infinity guaranteed to be 0?

Tags: c++, ieee-754

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613988/dividing-by-infinity), `n/inf` is expected to be zero for `n != 0`. What about when `n == 0`? According to IEEE-754, is `(0 / inf) == 0` always true?

Comment: What else would it be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematically, 0/0 is indeterminate, and 0/anything_else is zero.  IEEE-754 works the same way.

So 0/infinity will yield a zero.   0/0 will yield a NaN.

Note:   not all C++ implementations support IEEE floating point, and some that do so don't completely meet IEEE specifications, so this is not necessarily a C++ question.