# Is the inverse of std::numeric_limits::infinity() zero?

Tags: c++, floating-point, infinity

Is there anything in the C++ standard (or the IEEE 754 floating-point standard) that guarantees that `1./std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()` is zero (or at least a small number)?

Comment: Look into http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: [Very related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426734/is-0-divided-by-infinity-guaranteed-to-be-0).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, according to the GNU C library reference manual (assuming IEEE 754):

> Infinities propagate through calculations
>   as one would expect: for example, 2 + ∞ = ∞, 4/∞ =
>   0

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html

You may want to check if your C++ compiler uses IEEE 754:

*[How to check if C++ compiler uses IEEE 754 floating point standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777484/how-to-check-if-c-compiler-uses-ieee-754-floating-point-standard)*

Answer (score 14):

Any finite number divided by infinity results in zero under IEEE 754 (and therefore the same in most typical C++ implementations).

If the sign of the of numerator and denominator differ, the result will be negative zero, which is equal to zero.

Comment: Uhm, no, not exactly: if the finite number is negative it returns -0, which is not the same thing as 0 (although it compares equal).

Comment: Yeah, the proper wording would be "results in _a_ zero" :)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Both +0 and −0 in IEEE 754 specification level 2 (floating-point data) represent zero in level 1 (extended real numbers).

Answer (score 4):

IEEE 754-2008 6.1 says:

> The behavior of infinity in floating-point arithmetic is derived from the limiting cases of real arithmetic with operands of arbitrarily large magnitude, when such a limit exists. Infinities shall be interpreted in the affine sense, that is: −∞ < {every finite number} < +∞.
>
> Operations on infinite operands are usually exact and therefore signal no exceptions,…

Since the limit of 1/*x* as *x* increases without bound is zero, a consequence of this clause is that 1/∞ is zero.

Clause 6.3 tells us the sign of the result is +:

> When neither the inputs nor result are NaN, the sign of a product or quotient is the exclusive OR of the operands’ signs;…

Answer (score 2):

`if(std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559)
    yes();
else
    no();`

(see 18.3.2.4)

IEC 559, which is identical with IEEE 754, guarantees that to be the case. However, C++ *does not guarantee* in any way that IEC 559 is in place (although 99.99% of the time that's just what happens to be the case, you still need to verify to be sure).

Comment: Since nobody is likely to bother implementing and testing non-IEEE 754 platforms, one might as well `static_assert(std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559)`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: That's actually a good point. If your code relies on IEEE 754 particulars, then it won't work if these aren't present. So `static_assert` is a very valid option (possibly, probably, even the better one).